# Getting the first 52 characters OR LESS from a textbox

Tags: c#, string, richtextbox

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    timer1.Stop();
    richTextBox2.Text = "";
    richTextBox2.Paste();
    //this errors
    label5.Text = "Clipboard: " + richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0, 52) + "..."; 
    if (richTextBox2.Text == richTextBox3.Text) {
        richTextBox3.Paste();
        return;
    }
    else {
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

Here is my code for a feature on my program which is going to be a Clipboard Reader/Display. I've been searching for a way to grab a first specific amount of characters OR LESS but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I've already tried `richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0,52)` though it does not work, can someone help me out?

Comment: You have to check if the string actually is bigger than 52, then get the substring

Comment: It will error if there is no text in the richtextbox and you are trying to do a substring operation on it. It will throw and Index error. Can you make sure you textbox contains more than 52 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) method assumes that the requested number of characters are actually present in the string and it will throw an exception if that isn't the case. You could consider writing a custom method that would safely truncate your string:

```
public string Truncate(string s, int length, bool includeEllipsis = true)
{
     // Make sure you consider nulls
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
     {
          return s;
     }

     if (s.Length > length)
     {
          // Return the substring and an optional ellipsis
          return s.Substring(0, length) + (includeEllipsis ? "..." : "");
     }

     // The string was shorter than your requested length, so return it all
     return s;
}
```

Usage for your example might look like this:

```
label5.Text = "Clipboard: " + Truncate(richTextBox2.Text, 52);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that would be to get the substring that would need to be added to the result.

```
string text =  richTextBox2.Text.Length > 52 ? richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0,52) : richTextBox2.Text;
```

Then add the text which would be at most 52 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to the fact the string is less than 52 characters. You could fetch the substring based on the size of string (checking if it exceeds 52). For example

```
var result = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(0,Math.Min(52,richTextBox2.Text.Length));
```

If you want to eliminate the Math.Min, another possible approach is using Linq

```
var result = new string(richTextBox2.Text.Take(52).ToArray());
```